# Merge multiple arrays in one with the same key value in them

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I want to create an excel export file from the database. The data comes from 2 tables: `names` and `numbers`, the `names` table contains only unique rows, but the `numbers` can have multiple.
How can i merge these two arrays in one to achieve the same as the example array?

The arrays:

```
$names = array(
    array(
        "ID" => 1,
        "Name" => "Test1"
    ),
    array(
        "ID" => 2,
        "Name" => "Test2"
    )
);

$numbers = array(
    array(
        "ID" => 1,
        "Number" => "123"
    ),
    array(
        "ID" => 1,
        "Number" => "223"
    ),
    array(
        "ID" => 2,
        "Number" => "333"
    )
);
```

Example array:

```
$merged = array(
    array(
        "ID" => 1,
        "Name" => "Test1",
        "Number" => "123",
        "Number" => "223"
    ),
    array(
        "ID" => 2,
        "Name" => "Test2",
        "Number" => "333"
    )
);
```

Comment: Are ids unique in `$names`?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy yes

Comment: you can not have same key name as Number in your example array

Comment: Array with same key will override the previous key value, thus you may have to write like this: ```array(
        "ID" => 1,
        "Name" => "Test1",
        "Number" => array ("123", "223")
    )```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is to use two loops.

```
$merge = [];
foreach($names as $value) {
    $merge_sub = [];
    $merge_sub[] = $value['ID'];
    $merge_sub[] = $value['Name'];
    foreach($numbers as $n) {
        if($n['ID'] == $value['ID']) $merge_sub[] = $n['Number'];
    }
    $merge[] = $merge_sub;

}
```

Bear in mind that this adds the values without adding the keys, as you can't have several same key names, as each key change would overwrite the last key inserted with that same name. But this gives you an idea of an algorithm you can follow.

Although, you can try having the same keys but with an index like so :

```
$merge = [];
foreach($names as $value) {
    $merge_sub = [];
    $merge_sub['ID'] = $value['ID'];
    $merge_sub['Name'] = $value['Name'];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($numbers as $n) {
        if($n['ID'] == $value['ID']) $merge_sub['Number' . $i] = $n['Number'];
        $i++;
    }
    $merge[] = $merge_sub;

}
```